# Javascript search for string in selected elements and hide the html tag that contains that string

Tags: javascript, html, htmlcollection

I wrote a simple javascript code to find whether the string exists in innerHtml in selected elements, now I would like to hide element that contains that string but I'm not sure how to get the tag id or something to hide specified element. Here's my code.

```
 function hideTemplateOption(collToHide, hideText) {
    let collection = document.getElementsByClassName("product_tr_cus");
    if(collectionContains(collection,"test")) {
        console.log("contains");
    } else {
        console.log("nope");
    }
  }
  function collectionContains(collection, searchText) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if( collection[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1 ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
  hideTemplateOption();
```

Comment: In your `collectionContains` function, you've got the element in hand (`collection[i]`) so you can just add to its classList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `collection[i].style.display = 'none';` or better set it conditionally:

```js
function toggle(collection, searchText) {
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      var item_found = collection[i].innerText.toLowerCase().match(searchText);
      collection[i].style.display = item_found ? '' : 'none';
      if (item_found) {
          found = true;
      }
  }
  return found;
}

let collection = document.getElementsByClassName("product_tr_cus");
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
   toggle(collection, event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input/>
<ul>
  <li class="product_tr_cus">Foo</li>
  <li class="product_tr_cus">Bar</li>
  <li class="product_tr_cus">Baz</li>
  <li class="product_tr_cus">Quux</li>
</ul>
```

it will hide the node that have the string if you want the opposite then use:

```
collection[i].style.display = item_found ? '' : 'none';
```

and you probably will need better name for the function as well.

Comment: Your solution hides all elements within given collection even if i give collection[i]

Comment: @WinithePooh sorrry didn't tested this, check the update, you need to use `match`, I think `indexOf` is only for arrays, I've never seen usage of it with strings.

Comment: I fixed my problem, I had all my divs with product_tr_cus inside one big div with the same class name. Solution was to first select collection and then select all elements with given class inside this collection